# sumifs formula with date criteria not working

Tags: excel

I posted this yesterday, although realised the equation still doesn’t do quite what I want it to do.

(For some reasons it still SUMs values of dates outside the range specified. IE it still sums values that have years 2029, 2027 even though I want it to group values 2028 and sum them.

Would love any recommendation… Pretty sure the only way to solve this issue is incorporating the dates into the SUMIF equation. I still cannot seem to figure this one out!

This is my previous post...

Most of the SUMIFS criteria seems to work the way I want it to work, except the years criteria does not.
It seems that once 2028 is recognised in column “DO” (years) it will continue to SUM (even if the year is not 2028). Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
=IF(OR(AB3=0,DO3<>$DG$8),0,SUMIFS($I$3:$I3,$B$3:$B3,B3,$AB$3:$AB3,">0",$DO$3:$DO3,$DG$8))
```

The `$DG$8` cell reference is: 2028

| AB (use or not to use) | I (tons) | B (group) | DO (year) | What I want |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | 2 | 2028 | 200 |
| 0 | 200 | 2 | 2028 | 0 |
| 1 | 210 | 2 | 2028 | 410 |
| 1 | 240 | 2 | 2025 | 0 |
| 1 | 50 | 2 | 2024 | 0 |
| 1 | 200 | 3 | 2028 | 200 |
| 1 | 210 | 3 | 2025 | 0 |
| 1 | 240 | 3 | 2028 | 440 |
| 1 | 50 | 3 | 2024 | 0 |
| 0 | 240 | 3 | 2028 | 0 |

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your formula works perfect for me. MAke sure all numeric values are being read as numbers and not text

Comment: Thanks so much for your comment! I thought it did but unfortunately it 'sums' numbers that do not match the date(years) criteria

Comment: Are those years real numbers like `2028` or are they dates like `01/01/2028` but you formated the cell to show only the year?

Comment: Hi @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns! Thanks for the message... so the 'DO' column refers to the date column... i have then used 'year.'  So it's "=year(cell reference to date)."

Comment: it is deceiving because the first 100 rows seemed to show it works however it (for some strange reason) doesn't work for a lot of the data...

Answer (score 0):

I am a big fan of the new LET formula - as you can read it much better than the classic formulas.

Using a table (Insert > table) adds another level of "readability".

This is my setting:

[image]

And this is the formula:

```vb
=LET(isRelevant,IF(AND([@Use]>0,[@year]=year),TRUE,FALSE),
data,IF(isRelevant, FILTER([tons],
              ([group]=[@group])*([Use]>0)*([year]=year)*
              (ROW([Use])<=ROW()),0 ),0),
SUM(data))
```

The first step `isRelevant` checks if we need to calculate data for this row.

Second step `data` applies all your IFs to the FILTER function - referencing the columns by there names - and by that making it understandable.

Multiple conditions are concatenated by a * to become an `AND`.

`ROW([Use])<=ROW()` makes sure that only values including the current row plus the above rows are returned.